# libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: boost, shared-libraries, ubuntu-22.04, osm2pgsql

Following the indications found here: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-ubuntu-22-04-lts/ I'm trying to install Tile Server in Ubuntu 22.04

but I'm getting this error:

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo -u _renderd osm2pgsql -d gis --create --slim  -G --hstore --tag-transform-script ./OSM_src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.lua -C 2500 --number-processes 1 -S ./OSM_src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style ./OSM_src/data/azerbaijan-latest.osm.pbf
osm2pgsql: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The `libboost` library present is `1.74.0`:

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo apt install libboost-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libboost-dev is already the newest version (1.74.0.3ubuntu7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

raphy@pc:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -lah | grep libboost_filesystem.so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 mar 16  2022 libboost_filesystem.so -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.74.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  123K mar 16  2022 libboost_filesystem.so.1.74.0
```

Following the indications found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/950313/how-to-set-ld-library-path-permanently
I've set in `.bashrc` file:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so"
```

And, following the indications found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/201709/how-to-set-ld-library-path-in-ubuntu
I've set `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libboost.conf` as :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so
```

And then

```
sudo ldconfig
```

But still get the error:

`osm2pgsql: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How to solve the problem?

Comment: As 1.74 != 1.71, you need to recompile with the version you have now, or at least install the 1.71 run-time (which `apt` may then remove later thinking no _declared_ package uses it).  And more refined (but involved) solution is to create a package for `oms2pgsql` with a dependency on 1.71.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel how to recompile with the present version 1.74, if I installed `osm2pgsql` with `sudo apt install` via Ubuntu repo, following the indications here: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-ubuntu-22-04-lts/  ?

Comment: Hm, maybe something is then not quite right with that package because from what you write it seems to a) require 1.71 and b) not depend on it which would be wrong.  Sadly I do not have the time to debug this for you now but maybe you can get in touch with the authors of that piece.  But to illustrate, on my 22.04 I still have one boost sub-library of the 1.65 installed because something else must be requiring it.  The rest is 1.74 here too and all official package are properly rebuilt for it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm trying to understand if I could compile the `osm2pgsl` library with `libboost-1.74.0` version: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql

Comment: Generally, yes. Just install the appropriate `-dev` package, or the catch-all `libboost-all-dev`, and follow the instructions. As time passed since that tutorial was written, you may "simply" end up with 1.74 dependencies where it wrote about 1.71. Boost is fairly stable at the interfaces so it should just work.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel just tried to, but in the `make` phase: make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.74.0', needed by 'osm2pgsql'.  Stop.

Comment: You don't have `libboost-system-dev` install.  Maybe make it simpler and install `libboost-all-dev` to be covered.  Then retry (make sure to remove temporaries and earlier config leftover from that build.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel raphy@pc:~$ sudo apt install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.74.0.3ubuntu7).

Comment: Then you need to debug the Makefile above. Write a five-liner in C that tries to instantiate an object from that Boost library. If that works outside of the osm project there may be a problem there.  On normal systems all this tends to just work.  Good luck.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing . Thank you very mych @DirkEddelbuettel for your kind support

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel with `set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR,"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.74.0")` in `CmakeLists.txt` it still says: `No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.74.0', needed by 'osm2pgsql'.  Stop`